# UITableView not able to Show data and not fetch from array

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, uitableview, nsmutablearray

i am new in programming and iOS i am making an iPhone application like crud operation and inventory system i am not able to show data and fetch data in UITableView

But when Print array then this type of output produced.

```
2013-10-03 15:45:04.228 inventrymanagementsystem[1968:c07] name: (
    "<Category: 0x7453f40> (entity: Category; id: 0x744a3b0 <x-coredata://431EF8C4-5AAE-4AA8-ADFB-A09CE5731E2D/Category/p1> ; data: <fault>)",
    "<Category: 0x7456500> (entity: Category; id: 0x74501f0 <x-coredata://431EF8C4-5AAE-4AA8-ADFB-A09CE5731E2D/Category/p2> ; data: <fault>)",
    "<Category: 0x7456210> (entity: Category; id: 0x7450970 <x-coredata://431EF8C4-5AAE-4AA8-ADFB-A09CE5731E2D/Category/p3> ; data: <fault>)",
    "<Category: 0x7457830> (entity: Category; id: 0x743bd90 <x-coredata://431EF8C4-5AAE-4AA8-ADFB-A09CE5731E2D/Category/p4> ; data: <fault>)",
    "<Category: 0x7455cf0> (entity: Category; id: 0x7438670 <x-coredata://431EF8C4-5AAE-4AA8-ADFB-A09CE5731E2D/Category/p5> ; data: <fault>)",
    "<Category: 0x744b060> (entity: Category; id: 0x7438530 <x-coredata://431EF8C4-5AAE-4AA8-ADFB-A09CE5731E2D/Category/p6> ; data: <fault>)",
    "<Category: 0x74496f0> (entity: Category; id: 0x7436050 <x-coredata://431EF8C4-5AAE-4AA8-ADFB-A09CE5731E2D/Category/p7> ; data: <fault>)",
    "<Category: 0x744f290> (entity: Category; id: 0x744db90 <x-coredata://431EF8C4-5AAE-4AA8-ADFB-A09CE5731E2D/Category/p8> ; data: <fault>)",
    "<Category: 0x744eaa0> (entity: Category; id: 0x7439d40 <x-coredata://431EF8C4-5AAE-4AA8-ADFB-A09CE5731E2D/Category/p9> ; data: <fault>)",
    "<Category: 0x744fec0> (entity: Category; id: 0x74385c0 <x-coredata://431EF8C4-5AAE-4AA8-ADFB-A09CE5731E2D/Category/p10> ; data: <fault>)",
    "<Category: 0x744f410> (entity: Category; id: 0x7445de0 <x-coredata://431EF8C4-5AAE-4AA8-ADFB-A09CE5731E2D/Category/p11> ; data: <fault>)",
    "<Category: 0x74557c0> (entity: Category; id: 0x744ebe0 <x-coredata://431EF8C4-5AAE-4AA8-ADFB-A09CE5731E2D/Category/p12> ; data: <fault>)",
    "<Category: 0x7456190> (entity: Category; id: 0x7450b30 <x-coredata://431EF8C4-5AAE-4AA8-ADFB-A09CE5731E2D/Category/p13> ; data: <fault>)",
    "<Category: 0x7457010> (entity: Category; id: 0x7453180 <x-coredata://431EF8C4-5AAE-4AA8-ADFB-A09CE5731E2D/Category/p14> ; data: <fault>)",
    "<Category: 0x744b740> (entity: Category; id: 0x74524b0 <x-coredata://431EF8C4-5AAE-4AA8-ADFB-A09CE5731E2D/Category/p15> ; data: <fault>)"
)
```

I am not able to understand what's the problem.

**Code**

```
#import "IMScategoriesViewController.h"
#import "IMSAddCategoryViewController.h"
#import "IMSAppDelegate.h"
#import "Category.h"

@interface IMScategoriesViewController ()
@property (strong) NSMutableArray *categories;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSManagedObjectContext *managedObjectContext;
@property (nonatomic,retain) NSFetchedResultsController *fetchedresultcontroller;
@end
@implementation IMScategoriesViewController
- (NSManagedObjectContext *)managedObjectContext
{
    NSManagedObjectContext *context;
    id delegate = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
    if ([delegate performSelector:@selector(managedObjectContext)]) {
        context = [delegate managedObjectContext];
    }
    return context;
}
- (id)initWithStyle:(UITableViewStyle)style
{
    self = [super initWithStyle:style];
    if (self) {
        // Custom initialization
    }
    return self;
}
//- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated
//{
//    [super viewDidAppear:animated];

   - (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    // Fetch the devices from persistent data store
    NSManagedObjectContext *managedObjectContext = [self managedObjectContext];
   NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] initWithEntityName:@"Category"];
    self.categories = [[managedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:fetchRequest error:nil] mutableCopy];
    NSLog(@"name: %@",self.categories);
    [self.tableView reloadData];

// IMSAppDelegate * appDelegate = [UIApplication sharedApplication].delegate;
//    self.managedObjectContext = appDelegate.managedObjectContext;
//
//    // Fetching Records and saving it in "fetchedRecordsArray" object
//   self.categories = [[appDelegate getallcategories]mutableCopy];
//    NSLog(@"name: %@",self.categories);
//    [self.tableView reloadData];
}
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    // Return the number of sections.
    return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    // Return the number of rows in the section.
    return [self.getallcategories count];
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"cell";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];
 //   UITableViewCell *cell = [UITableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"Cell"];

    //add this
    if (cell == nil)
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:@"cell"];
    Category * category = [self.getallcategories objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    cell.textLabel.text = [category name];
    return cell;
}
```

Comment: How many rows are showing up when the view is loaded?  In your `cellForRowAtIndexPath` method, what happens when you put `NSLog(@"This category is: %@", category);` ?

Comment: By the way, you should be using an `NSFetchedResultsController` instead of fetching the entire set of `Categories` since it only fetches what is needed to be shown on screen.

Comment: When Put 'NSLog(@"This category is: %@", category);' the this is show in output  2013-10-04 08:31:16.062  name: (
    "<Category: 0x845c8d0> (entity: Category; id: 0x845b720 <x-coredata://431EF8C4-5AAE-4AA8-ADFB-A09CE5731E2D/Category/p1> ; data: <fault>)",
    "<Category: 0x845cb80> (entity: Category; id: 0x845b730 <x-coredata://431EF8C4-5AAE-4AA8-ADFB-A09CE5731E2D/Category/p2> ; data: <fault>)",
    "<Category: 0x845cbe0> (entity: Category; id: 0x845b740 <x-coredata://431EF8C4-5AAE-4AA8-ADFB-A09CE5731E2D/Category/p3> ; data: <fault>)",

Comment: Why aren't you using `[self.categories objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];` instead of `[self.getallcategories objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];` ?  You set the fetch request result into `self.categories` in `viewDidLoad` method.  Same goes for your `numberOfRowsInSection` method...

Comment: If you free so checked my app in team viewer and tell me the problem thnkes.

Comment: i checked it no change same result show

Comment: getallcategories is NSMutableArray and categories is NSArray. we use both one by one but problem not solved

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two problems.

1) You are accessing `name` which is a property on an [NSEntityDescription](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/CoreDataFramework/Classes/NSEntityDescription_Class/NSEntityDescription.html) object.  Maybe you are just doing this temporarily, but if you created a `name` property in your `Category` entity, then you'll have to change that property name to something else (e.g. `categoryName` or `itemName`) since this is already reserved.

2) When you put an NSLog in the `cellForRowAtIndexPath` method to show the `category`, it returned an array of categories, so you're obviously not accessing the data source correctly.

The problem is that you're using `[self.getallcategories objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];` instead of accessing the original array that you created in the `viewDidLoad` method which should instead be:

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    // Access the proper array here that you loaded in viewDidLoad
    return [self.categories count];
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"cell";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];

    if (cell == nil)
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:@"cell"];

    // Access the proper array here that you loaded in viewDidLoad
    Category * category = [self.categories objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    cell.textLabel.text = [category name];
    return cell;
}
```

As I mentioned, you should be using [NSFetchedResultsController](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/CoreData/Reference/NSFetchedResultsController_Class/Reference/Reference.html) instead of executing a fetch like that for a tableview.  NSFetchedResultsController is optimized for acting as the datasource for table views since it only fetches objects that are showing on screen.

Also, you are using the old way of instantiating a new table view cell.  You should be using prototype cells (set the cell identifier in Interface Builder) and then your code would look like this:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    // Make sure your prototype cell in Interface Builder has an identifier called "Cell"
    UITableViewCell *cell = [UITableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"Cell"];

    // Access the proper array here that you loaded in viewDidLoad
    Category *category = [self.categories objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    // Assuming the Category entity has somePropertyNameHere method
    cell.textLabel.text = category.somePropertyNameHere;
    return cell;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

please check your delegate and data source connection. set your table view delegate and data source.
@interface myViewController : UIViewController  {...}   set it. and refer table view tutorial

Comment: i am checked the delegate and data source connection.connection is ok